# Como finalizar el método si la sesión es correcta

Tags: java, bucle-for, while

Quisiera saber si hay un código similar al `System.exit()` que me permite finalizar el método o el `while` cuando se ingresa correctamente le dejo el código. En mi caso es la cedula cuando ingreso correctamente me sigue ejecutando osea quiero terminar y continuar con otro proceso la que cree la instancia `run.Menuop();`

```
public int sesion() {
  int n = 0;
  int cont=4;
  int ci = 1718472085;
  int ced = 0;

  do {            
    while(ced!=1718472085) {
      Scanner teclado= new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Introduzca la cedula: ");
      ced=teclado.nextInt();
      if(ced==ci) {
        System.out.println("exito");
        //Operadores run=new Operadores();
        System.out.println("Continue");
        //run.Menuop();
      } else {
        --cont;
        System.out.println("cedula incorrecta, " + "le queda " + cont + " intentos");
        if (cont==0) {
          System.out.println("Se ha excedido el numero de intentos");
          System.exit(0);
        }      
      } 
    }
  } while (ced==ci);

  return ced;
}
```

Comment: es `break;` lo que buscas?

Comment: Supongo que si pero lo intente y no funciona

Comment: dónde exactamente quieres que termine? pon una marca en el código

Comment: Que termine el metodo porque si esta tal como esta el codigo me sigue saliendo como bucle

Answer (score 0):

Tienes el bucle do-while mal. Tienes un while dentro del bucle que evalua la condición contraria a la de salida del bucle. Por un lado le dices,

mientras ced sea distinto a 1718472085 haz lo siguiente ...
y como condición de permanencia en el bucle le dices que mientras que sean iguales, que se repita el bucle exterior.

Te paso tu código modificado con un método main para que lo puedas ejecutar y compruebes que funciona

```
public class BucleDoWhile {

static Scanner teclado;

public BucleDoWhile() {

}

public static int sesion() {
    //int n = 0;
    int cont = 4;
    int ci = 1718472085;
    int ced = 0;
    do {
        teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Introduzca la cedula: ");
        ced = teclado.nextInt();
        if (ced == ci) {
            System.out.println("exito");
            System.out.println("Continue");
        } else {
            --cont;
            if (cont == 0) {
                System.out.println("Se ha excedido el numero de intentos");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("cedula incorrecta, " + "le queda " + cont + " intentos");
            }   
        }
    } while(ced != ci);

    return ced;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int sesion = sesion();

    System.out.println(sesion);
    System.out.println("... y el programa sigue ...");

}
```

}

Espero que te sirva, saludos!!